# How to use count in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.arrayList;
public class Trial{

public Trial(){
boolean check = true;
int count = 0;
ArrayList<Company> c;
}
public boolean addCompany(String companyName, int numOfEmployees, String nameOfCEO, String street, String city, String state) {
        //----

        if(count < c.size()){

            Company comp = new Company(companyName, nameOfCEO, numOfEmployees, street, city, state);

            c.add(count, comp);

            count++;
            check = true;
        }


        for(int j = 0; j < companyList.size(); j++){

            if(c.get(j).getCompanyName().equals(companyName))

                companyList.remove(count);

                check = false;

                break;

            }
        }

        return check;
    }
}
```

I want to use the addCompany method to add a comp (object) and return true if the company is added, and false if there's a duplicate comp (object) in the array. The addCompany method is not adding comp (object) into the ArrayList c. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code declared 3 *local variables* inside the constructor, which are all unused. There are no fields in the class.

Move the declarations outside the constructor, and fix the `import` to spell the class name correctly (case-sensitive).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Trial {

    boolean check = true;
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<Company> c;

    public Trial(){
    }
```

After that, you can begin to fix all the other errors in the code.

I would highly recommend that you start using an IDE, since that will greatly help you fix problems before there are so many of them that you get overwhelmed.